# SPFile file = web. GetFile (fileUrl); but sometimes they pass in incorrect fileUrl

Tags: spfile

Will this work or break if fileUrl is blank or does not even exists?

```
SPFile file = web. GetFile (fileUrl); 

if (file == null)
{
    file.delete()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the exists property instead of null, GetFile method doesn't return null if file doesn't exist

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile(fileurl);

if(file.Exists) 
{
    //code here
}
```